# Is there any way to disable automatic recalculation of UnitPrice when Quantity changes?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

I have a flow that changes Quantity to OpportunityLineItem. This automatically changes the UnitPrice. I found a way to revert back - keep the original UnitPrice and do 2 updates to get back the past value. But I don't like this solution. Is there any way to disable UnitPrice recalculation globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the [OpportunityLineItem Object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm?q=opportunitylineitem)

> When updating these records:
>
> If you specify Quantity without specifying the UnitPrice, the UnitPrice value will be adjusted to accommodate the new Quantity value, and the TotalPrice will be held constant.
>
> If you specify both Discount and Quantity, you must also specify either TotalPrice or UnitPrice so the system can determine which one to automatically adjust.

Your application probably falls into the former category, you are just changing the `Quantity` so the system is holding `TotalPrice` invariant hence `UnitPrice` is altered to be `TotalPrice / Quantity`.

So, your Flow should set both `Quantity` and `UnitPrice` in the Update Records element